# Extension of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

Let $ p = 2 $, and Let $  H $ be a subgroup of a direct product of copies of $ S_{3} $. Why $ H $ is an extension of a $ 3 $-group by a $ 2 $-group, and $ H/O_{p^{\prime}}(H) $ is a $ 2 $-group ?

Comment: Because $S_3$ has these properties (and the second property follows immediately from the first).

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh yes, Since $ S_{3} $ is an extension of $ Z_{3} $ by $ Z_{2} $.